# Developer warning when running my app and connecting it to FireBase. Failed to post notification on channel "null"

Tags: java, android

I'm following a tutorial to create a Login/Register and connect this with `FireBase`. It isn't letting me add images for my code yet so I will just paste it if that works...

I have added all the dependencies for the `gradle`

I have added the internet option for the `XML`
When I run the app it runs fine and when I enter the username and password and click the register button it gives the

"Failed to post..."

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()

        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }


    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
            defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.saiyarram.perfectit"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
            // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
            // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
            // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
            exclude 'META-INF/notice'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            ex

        clude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            })
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.2'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
            compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
            compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        }
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    package com.example.saiyarram.perfectit;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        private Button 

    LogInButton;
        private Button RegisterButton;
        private EditText UserNameEditText;
        private EditText PasswordEditText;

        private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        LogInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogInButton);
        RegisterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RegisterButton);
        UserNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserNameEditText);
        PasswordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordEditText);

        LogInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        RegisterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        if(view == LogInButton){
            //will login the user
        }
        if(view == RegisterButton){
            RegisterUser();
        }
    }
    private void RegisterUser(){
        String Email = UserNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String Password = PasswordEditText.getText().toString().trim();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter An Email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Password)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter A Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email,Password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Could not register",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ;
                    }
                }
            });
        System.out.println("Stuck here1");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is always good practice to copy paste your code directly into your poste instead of uploading screenshots!

Comment: Can you add also the error of the IDE to have a better look.